# How to replace a content on specific patter using sed without losing info?

Tags: awk, sed

I have a text file with a bunch of data. I was able to extract exactly what I want using sed; but
I need to replaced only the specific pattern I searched without losing the other content from the file.

Im using the following sed command; but I need to the replacement; but dont know how to do it.

```
cat file.txt | sed -rn '/([a-z0-9]{2}\s){6}/p' > output.txt
```

The sed searches for the following pattern: ## ## ## ## ## ##, but I want to replace that pattern like this: ######-######.

```
cat file.txt | sed -rn '/([a-z0-9]{2}\s){6}/p' > output.txt
Output:

1         | ec eb b8 7b e3 c0  47                
9         | 90 20 c2 f6 3d c0  1/1/1             
25        | 00 fd 45 3d a7 80  31

Desired Output:

1         | ecebb8-7be3c0  47                
9         | 9020c2-f63dc0  1/1/1             
25        | 00fd45-3da780  31

Thanks
```

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` program.

```
awk '
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="|" }
{
  $2=substr($2,1,3) substr($2,5,2) substr($2,8,2)"-" substr($2,11,2) substr($2,14,2) substr($2,17,2) substr($2,19)
}
1
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, setting `FS` and `OFS` as `|` for `awk` program. Then in 2nd field using `awk`'s `substr` function keeping only needed values as per shown samples of OP. Where `substr` function works on method of printing specific indexes/position number values(eg: from which value to which value you need to print). Then saving required values into 2nd field itself and printing current line then.

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{$3=$3$4$5"-"$6$7$8; print $1"\t",$2,$3,$NF}' file
1        | ecebb8-7be3c0 47
9        | 9020c2-f63dc0 1/1/1
25       | 00fd45-3da780 31
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/ (\S\S) (\S\S) (\S\S)/ \1\2\3/;s//-\1\2\3/' file
```

Pattern match 3 spaced pairs twice, removing the spaces between the 2nd and 3rd pairs and replacing the first space in the 2nd match by `-`.

Comment: Great!.. This is as simple line and works great.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract specific substrings, you'll need to write a more specific regex to pull out exactly those.

```sh
sed -rn '/([a-z0-9]{2})\s([a-z0-9]{2})\s([a-z0-9]{2})\s([a-z0-9]{2})\s([a-z0-9]{2})\s([a-z0-9]{2})\s/\1\2\3-\4\5\6/' file.txt > output.txt
```

Notice also how easy it is to avoid the [useless `cat`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

`\s` is generally not portable; the POSIX equivalent is `[[:space:]]`.